# Exclamation mark appearing at the end of last value in string array C

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

For some reason, when I malloc for stringArr[n], the value at strArr[n-1] either adds a '!' at the end or replaces the last char with a '!'. In GDB, when assigning to strArr[n], the string looks find but when n is incremented, when mallocing strArr[n] (n+1 in this case), strArr[n-1] gets the '!' added. I have no clue why this is happening.

```
char** stringArr = malloc(sizeof(char*)*28);
char* token;

int n = 0;
while(n < 28)
{
    token = //tokenize something here
    stringArr[n] = malloc(sizeof(token)+1);
    strcpy(stringArr[n], token);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
stringArr[n] = malloc(sizeof(token)+1);
```

You don't want this. Because `sizeof` of a pointer is fixed (for a system). So you are allocating fixed length string for copying each tokenized string(which may have length more than what you have allocated). So `strcpy` is accessing memory that is not even allocated. This is undefined behavior.

This will be

```
stringArr[n] = malloc(strlen(token)+1);
```

Now you are making sure that dynamically allocated memory has length capable of holding the string (NUL terminated char array) to be copied.

Also another thing, check the return value of `malloc`. Cases when `malloc` fails it won't run into undefined behavior accessing it. Free the dynamically allocated memory when you are done working with it.

Comment: Wow, can't believe I did that. It's the end of the semester in my systems class and I'm still getting caught up with little mistakes :(